# Ключ сессии вообще не существует если указать unset

Tags: php, javascript, сессия

Вот вью

```
if (isset($_SESSION['msg'])) {
  if ($_SESSION['msg']['type'] == 'success') {
    ?><script type="text/javascript">toastr.success("<?=$_SESSION['msg']['message']?>");</script><?
  }else {
    ?><script type="text/javascript">toastr.error("<?=$_SESSION['msg']['message']?>");</script><?
  } 
  unset($_SESSION['msg']);
}
```

Вот код контроллера

```
if (isset($_POST['invite'])) {
      include_once ROOT.'/system/Models/Invites.php';
      $res = Invites::AddInvite($_POST['invite']);

      if ($res == true) {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => 'Инвайт добавлен');
      }else{
        $_SESSION['msg'] = array('type' => 'error', 'message' => 'Инвайт не добавлен');
      } 

      header('Location: /JokersMadeAGreatDeal/invites');
    }else{die('ATATA');}
```

Посылается пост запрос, где в сессию под ключем msg добавляется массив. После перенаправляется на другую страницу, где другой контроллер подключает вьюшку. Но этот ключ сессии уже стерт.

Не срабатывает запуск js, но если убрать unset($_SESSION['msg']), все прекрасно работает.
Подскажите в чем может быть дело?

Comment: Задаю ключ в контроллере и через header location Отправляю на страницу нужную страницу

Comment: а по исходникам страницы что там? Есть предположение что где-то еще используется ваш msg

Comment: а выше строчка откуда?

Comment: @Manitikyl из вьюшки

Answer (score 0):

Я понял, я голова, дело в том, что у меня принято в конце контроллера возвращать true, и в таком случае класс роута бы не искал дальнейшие совпадения, а я забыл это сделать и роут нашел дальнейшее совпадение и в POST запросе его отработал. Вот и получалось что ключ удалялся не отобразившись.

Дети хлопают в ладоши, всем спасибо ответ хороший!